# How to concatenate Resultset to String variable

Tags: java, sql

I want to get my ItemName columns value to one String separate from commas.

I tried like this.but its not working

```
        String sql = "SELECT `ItemName` FROM `invoicelist` WHERE `InvoiceId` = '"+invoicenum+"' ";
        try {
        ResultSet rs =   CODE.DbAccess.getdata(sql);


        while (rs.next()) {
        String em =  rs.getString("ItemName");

         description = em.replace("\n", ",");
         System.out.println(description);  


        }
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate all `ItemName` values from the resultset ?

Comment: Hello, is it MySQL, Oracle, Sql-server, PostgreSQL, ... ? Do you want an SQL solution or a Java solution ?

Comment: It does not seem that you want a  real concatenation, but just some string replace!!
can you give an example of the original ItemName and the result you expect?

Comment: @DanielE. Java Solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change to this, if you want to do the concatenation in java:

```
String sql = "SELECT `ItemName` FROM `invoicelist` WHERE `InvoiceId` = '" + invoicenum + "' ";
try { 
    ResultSet rs =   CODE.DbAccess.getdata(sql);

    while (rs.next()) {
        description += rs.getString("ItemName") + ",";
    } 

    description = description.substring(0, description.length() - 1);

    //System.out.println(description);  
}
```

If you want to concatenate in query then you could search for `GROUP_CONCAT() function`

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql = "SELECT `ItemName` FROM `invoicelist` WHERE `InvoiceId` = '" + invoicenum + "' ";
try { 
    ResultSet rs =   CODE.DbAccess.getdata(sql);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // used to store string and append data further if you want
    while (rs.next()) {
        builder.append(rs.getString("ItemName").append(","); // adding data/Item name to builder and appending comma after adding item name
    } 
    if(builder.length() > 0){ // if there's some data inside builder
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1); // remove last appended comma from builder
    }
    System.out.println("Command Separated Data" + builder.toString()); // final data of item name
}
```

**Other way is to concate result from SQL itself.(here's a MySQL compatible code)**

```
String sql = "SELECT group_concat(`ItemName`) as items FROM `invoicelist` WHERE `InvoiceId` = '" + invoicenum + "' ";
try { 
    ResultSet rs =   CODE.DbAccess.getdata(sql);
    String data = "";
    while (rs.next()) {
        data = rs.getString("items")
    } 
    System.out.println("Command Separated Data" + data); 
}
```